# 'String Indices must be integers error' when string indices are integers

Tags: python, pca

I am getting the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-996316424e3b> in <module>
     11     #print (i)
     12     plt.text(pca[i, 0], pca[i, 1], str(clusters[i]),
---> 13              color=colours[y[i]],
     14              fontdict={'weight': 'bold', 'size': 50}
     15         )

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Even though my string indices are integers, as seen in the code below:

```
X = df.drop('season', axis = 1)
y = df.season
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_std = scaler.fit_transform(X)
clusters = agg_cluster.fit_predict(X_std)
pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(X_std)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
colours = 'rbg'
for i in range(pca.shape[0]):
    plt.text(pca[i, 0], pca[i, 1], str(clusters[i]),
             color=colours[y[i]],
             fontdict={'weight': 'bold', 'size': 50}
        )
```

The season feature only includes four possible values and is numerical (0,1,2,3).

Comment: What exactly is `y`?

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?  Sometimes, in my experience, when a Matplotlib function gets invalid input (wrong type or value), it will throw an exception from its internals, rather... ungracefully.

Comment: It seems rather obvious that `y[i]` is not an integer, because Python said so. I've never heard of Python lying about such things ;)

Comment: Check the `type(y)`.